# How to parse get url in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

```
// route
TestTestAppBundle_foobar:
    pattern:  /foobar
    defaults: { _controller: TestTestAppBundle:Default:fooar }


//controller

public function foobarAction(Request $request)
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $method = $request->getMethod();
        $var =  $request->query->keys();
        $response = new Response('Content', 200, array('content-type' => 'text/html'));
        $response->setContent($var);
        return $response;
    }
```

When I am making a call to URL

> /foobar?foo=bar

then it returns empty array. Instead it should return the GET parameters.

How to handle GET request in symfony?

Comment: I found the solution way back, It was nginx and php-fpm issue, nginx was removing all the query parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a slash in `pattern` e.g

```
pattern:  /foobar/
```

It will also ensure that route will match both `/foobar` and `/foobar/` pattern.

Answer (score 2):

It won't ever work like this for 2 reasons:

- As far as I can see, it's getting query string as it should, but `setContent` is bit messed up. First argument shouldn't be array, but string. So `$var[0]` will work and set content to `foo`.
- Also, your routing is bit wrong. Your pattern is `/foobar`, but you are trying to open `/foobar/` which isn't the same. If you set `pattern: /foobar/`, you could use both `/foobar/` and `/foobar` (which in fact redirects to `/foobar/`).

However, `query->keys()` this will return just keys in this case. If you want to get both keys and values, you should use `query->all()` or `query->get('foo')` for value of `foo` only.

Also, you don't need to use `$request = $this->getRequest();` as request is already first argument in your action. You can just use it straight away.

`setContent` is also bit useless in this case as first argument of `Response` already calls it, so you can set it there without using extra function call.

Comment: In poster's defence, I think he is experimenting with the framework. Also he wanted to print the GET parameters as output. I think there isn't any problem there. As `$var` is null, He did not get the exception on setting `Response`.

Comment: @m2mdas Yes . I am experimenting  with the framework. And checking every thing by printing

Comment: @Tauquir Where exactly is that `NULL` printed? I don't see any `var_dump` anywhere. Could you update the question with exact steps you took? It wouldn't print "NULL" if `$var` was NULL.

@m2mdas I'm fully aware of that. I just took the chance and gave some tips to him :)

Comment: I mean null is nothing. Yes It is not printing any thing.

Comment: Are you trying on dev or prod environment? If on prod, try to clear cache if you haven't done so, it could help. I noticed also typo in `TestTestAppBundle:Default:*fooar*`, that could cause also blank screen in prod environment.

Comment: I am trying things in dev environment.

Comment: That's really odd. It should return empty array in case there isn't anything. It seems as if `$var` wasn't set. What's `$request->getQueryString()` returning?